# Passing Data from Azure Function Filter to Function

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-webjobssdk

I have delegated `Bearer Token Validation`  to `Azure Function Invocation Filter`. It validates the token and gets the claims.  Now i'm trying to pass those claims or `ClaimsPrincipal` object  into Function.

```
     public override Task OnExecutingAsync(
                FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
             var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
             handler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
             principal = handler.ValidateToken(jwtToken,
                    new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidIssuer = issuer,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                        SignatureValidator = (t, param) => new 
                                                        JwtSecurityToken(t),
                        NameClaimType = "sub"

                    }, out var token);
     }
```

I see a dictionary called `Properties` in `FunctionExecutingContext`. But as per the documentation it is used for passing data between filters.

So   `executingContext.Properties["claims"] = principal;` doesn't pass data to function.

We could achieve it with `RouteData` in WebAPI but not sure if it's possible to do it in Azure Functions. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are a bit limited -there's no generic property bag plumbed through like Request.Properties. 
You could have the Filter be on a class with your functions, and then the filter can set instance fields when it executes; and your function can read the fields.  You may need to set a JobActivator and ensure that each invocation gets a new class instance.

Comment: Thanks.   I am using Azure Functions.  classes are static. so i think it's not possible to have new class instance each time a function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution already, but there is a solution when you are using the function as http trigger. The first argument of you're function will be a `HttpRequestMessage` object (`req`). Retrieve this argument in the filter like this:

```
HttpRequestMessage req = (HttpRequestMessage)executingContext.Arguments.First().Value;
```

You can use `req`.Properties to add custom data and read this from inside your function.